# Raspbmc CEC with Panasonic TX-P42X50B (Viera link)

Tags: raspbmc, hdmi, remote

I've been desperately trying to get my TV and Rasbpi to work together such that I can use the TV remote to control my Pi.

The Pi is plugged in via an HDMI cable (apparently all HDMI cables have to be fully wired, so it shouldn't be an issue with the cable, or could it be?), I've tried both HDMI ports.

The CEC adapted is on the Pi, and can be seen in *System->Input Devices->Peripherals*. I've tried power cycling the TV and Pi, with enabling and disabling the CEC/Viera Link each time.

Every time I click "Viera Link" in the Viera menu, I get "feature not available". I recently reinstalled raspbmc from scratch to see what I could do, and I definitely have the latest version (although it's never worked for me anyway).

Does anyone know how I could get this working, it seems like a lot of people have it working out the box, so this is incredibly frustrating.

Comment: If the error is coming up on the TV side of things, indicating "feature not available", perhaps the issue is with the TV and now raspbmc.  Have you tried another/different brand TV?

Comment: I haven't, but many people seem to have this working. I don't have another TV to test it on, unfortunately, and I don't see any way of debugging this easily. The TV says "not available" when it doesn't detect a compatible device, so the error could be on either side, or something to do with the cable, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use my Pi with Raspbmc on it with my Viera TV to watch movies. My remote controls the Pi perfectly but Im not using Viera Link at all. I just have my Pi connected to the HDMI port, just as if was a gaming console, and when using the remote with the Pi connected and it turned on it automatically controls the Pi with my remote. No configuration was needed and I never touched anything to do with the Viera Link on my remote.

The hdmi cable I'm using is version 1.4 (with ethernet support) which may be the reason why the two devices can communicate and yours might not be able too because its an older version. I have seen a setting on the Pi that changes settings with TV remote support.  I think the Viera Link is for watching videos, music and photos off a USB plugged into the TV's usb port.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try and get a better (= more expensive I suppose) HDMI cable and report back...

Comment: Bought a better cable ("with ethernet support") and now it works! Thanks.

Comment: For saying thanks, you can +1 the answer in addition to accepting as the solution.

Comment: To my knowledge the Pi does not use any ethernet over HDMI. Just CEC which is a simpler serial connection.